# Mysql Auto increment not incrementing value automatically

Tags: mysql, sql

Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra

| Student_id   | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment

As I need when I insert data in table its auto increment automatically insert value but when i try this query `insert into student_info values("Harry",75,89,50,56);`
I am getting this error as
**ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**

And when I write query like this

```
insert into student_info values(1,"Harry",75,89,50,56);
```

The data get inserted

I dont want to insert Student_id by manually as I have declared this column as `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Mysql Version 8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the columns in the `INSERT` operation.  For example:

```
INSERT INTO student_info (Name, SomeValue, AnotherValue, AnotherColumn, AndAnotherColumn) 
VALUES ("Harry",75,89,50,56)
```

The database engine isn't going to infer what you want based on whether the primary key is `AUTOINCREMENT` or not.  It's just looking for the number of values provided and the number of columns in the table.  If those don't match, you need to specify the columns you want to use.

As an aside, you really should *always* specify the columns in these operations.  Otherwise as soon as you change any table schema then operations which *should* still work won't.

Comment: So as a Student_id column what should i insert when writing the query ?

Comment: @TapanRadadiya: What value do you *want* to insert into that column?  That would be the value you include here.  If that column is the auto-incrementing primary key for the table then you wouldn't insert any value, you'd let the table increment the value it has.  It's not really clear what you're asking in that comment.

Comment: As you mention "If that column is the auto-incrementing primary key for the table then you wouldn't insert any value," so when i write data insert query i dont want to mention auto_increment column in the query 
But when i am not mentioning  that value it is throwing me error
And when i insert my auto_increment column's value in my insert query then it is inserting perfectly

Comment: @TapanRadadiya: What is the exact error?  What is the exact operation you're performing?  What is the exact table structure?  Please update the question to include a [mcve] which can be used to demonstrate the problem.  (Something that can be used in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) or [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/).)  We can only help with specifics, not with vague assertions that "it doesn't work".

Comment: ohk Thank you for your time i have solved this query thank you for your time

Answer (score 3):

You just need to specify the list of columns explicitly in your query and omit the auto-incremented one. You haven't specified which columns you have in your table, but it will be something like:

```
INSERT INTO student_info(Name, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5) 
VALUES("Harry",75,89,50,56);
```

Comment: Yes i have also try this

Comment: then it is showing incorrect integer value for column student_id at row 1

Answer (score 1):

You need to write you request like that :

```
INSERT INTO student_info(Student_id, Name, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4) 
VALUES('',"Harry",75,89,50,56);
```

As you need to pass value to your id autoincrement, pass "empty" value, it will generate the new value by itself.

Comment: Incorrect integer value: ' ' for column 'Student_id' at row 1

Comment: Showing this error

Comment: You must have a misconfiguration. 
Show us your entire table configuration with all fields. On my side it works